# How to see what processes produce usage spikes on Ubuntu server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

As I was monitoring one of my servers it seems that there are some unusual processor usage spikes as seen in this  image:
[image] 
that occur as can be seen from this graphic in a repeated interval.

This server runs Ubuntu 14.04 server edition and I've installed `ubuntu-desktop` just to run chrome and show a grafana page on a monitor. Also, there are several web servers and services running but none of them have any traffic at the moment.

I have tried to investigate this usage spikes by using `top` and `htop` commands to see which process are using the cores of the processor. It seems the only processes that are using the cores is chrome (with a usage of at most 30% sometimes in the processor).

Can someone please point me out how can I investigate what creates those usage spikes? I am worried that something is wrong somewhere as the repeated intervals happen since a few days ago

Answer (score 1):

You may try to place some script like below into cron:

```
ps -eo pid,pcpu,comm | grep -v 0.0 >> /home/user/process_load.log
```

And check your server and application's cron jobs, as the load is periodical it may be some jobs running every 2 hours.

UPD:
the better way:

```
/bin/date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S >> /home/user/process_load.log && /bin/ps -eo pid,pcpu,comm | /bin/grep -v 0.0 >> /home/user/process_load.log
```

Comment: In response to you, most of the average load I can see so far is the following: [http://pastebin.com/5QjqyKCE](http://pastebin.com/5QjqyKCE)

Comment: @roshkattu did you check your cron and application logs? Is there something interesting? I've got very similar spikes when I restart my unicorn_rails server. You also can checkout IO load, it can influence as well